# Replace an unknown string within a line using Bash

Tags: bash, sed

I want to be able to modify `db001` with a string I pass into the command via CLI. At any given time `db001` could be a different value so I can't just look for that value.

```
./myscript modify_db <new value>
```

## myfile.txt

```
./myscript modify_db mynewdbname002
Before: database_node=db001.mydomain.local
After: database_node=mynewdbname002.mydomain.local    

./myscript modify_db db003
Before: database_node=mynewdbname002.mydomain.local
After: database_node=db003.mydomain.local
```

Comment: So the second call is supposed to look for the replacement string from the previous call?

Comment: correct. i dont care what the previous call was. maybe someone edits the file manually after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a script like, just like below taking an input argument having the replacement value,

```
#!/bin/bash
perl -lpe "s/database_node=(\w+)/database_node=$1/g" file
```

and just do

```
./script.sh newdbname
```

Use the `-i` flag for in-place replacement and `-i.bak` for in-place replacement with a backup of your original file

```
perl -lpe -i.bak "s/database_node=(\w+)/database_node=$1/g" file
```

(or) with a simple `bash` function

```
function replaceFile() {
    perl -lpe -i.bak "s/database_node=(\w+)/database_node=$1/g" file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `sed` command inside your script:

```
sed "s/^\(database_node=\)[^.]*/\1$1/" file
```

**Example:**

```
s='database_node=db001.mydomain.local'

repl() {
   sed "s/^\(database_node=\)[^.]*/\1$1/" <<< "$s";
}
```

and call it as:

```
repl mynewdbname002
database_node=mynewdbname002.mydomain.local

repl db003
database_node=db003.mydomain.local
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid trying to produce the new state from the previous state and rather just use a template :

```
function modify_db() { 
    echo "database_node=$1.mydomain.local"
}
```

I use `echo` here for illustration but you should obviously do whatever you want to do with the `"database_node=$1.mydomain.local"`.

Supposing it should modify the only line starting with `database_node` from a file `db_conf` after having printed the old value :

```
function modify_db() {
    echo "Before: $(grep '^database_node=' db_conf)"
    sed -i "s/^database_node=.*\.mydomain\.local/database_node=$1.mydomain.local/" db_conf
    echo "After: $(grep '^database_node=' db_conf)"
}
```